# Why is w3c validator complaining about <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

Tags: html

The http://validator.w3.org/check 
is complaining about

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Why?

Below is the complete HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" >
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <title></title>
        <!--I dont particularly apreciate bundles in their current beta state. I used them only for big libraries only-->    
        <link href="/Content/EricMeyerReset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" >
        <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >


    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript" > </script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.19/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <!--http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#Knockout_Releases_on_the_CDN_10-->
        <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


        <!--If Jquery fails the fall back to local version--> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            !window.jQuery && document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's not actually valid. With that being said, it's not really hurting anything, but there are ways to get rid of it and accomplish the same results, using a .htaccess file https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/html5boilerplate/bRtrFSrKjtI/AOa44To23nMJ .

Answer (score 0):

I suppose is not "Valid" which I think is total bs. So here:
In IIS

```
 <configuration>
       <system.webServer>
          <httpProtocol>
           <customHeaders>
           <clear/>
           <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge, chrome=1"/>
      </customHeaders>
          </httpProtocol>
       </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

In Apache

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

        BrowserMatch MSIE ie

        Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1" env=ie

      IfModule>

    IfModule>
```